# (x)copy a directory, not only files

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, xcopy

I want to copy a directory to another one.
Let's say we have following structure:

```
DIR   src\
FILE      file

DIR dest\
```

This copies src\file to dest\file, but I want dest\src\file.

```
xcopy /E src dest
```

/S and /E switches doesn't seem to affect this.

Comment: look at`/i`: "If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination does not exist, xcopy assumes destination specifies a directory name and creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files into the new directory. By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether Destination is a file or a directory." http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx

Comment: so with /i, you would set your destination to `\dest\src`. also make sure you are not refering to your source using any wildcards, and don't put a backslash at the end of the source path.